# BusyBox: Error during make

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, udev, busybox

I try to install BusyBox 1.20.2 on a embedded system with PowerPc. At first I want to try it with the default config. 
So this are the commands

```
make defconfig
make
```

And this is the result:

```
ma-bash-3.2# make
  CC      miscutils/ubi_tools.o
miscutils/ubi_tools.c: In function 'ubi_tools_main':
miscutils/ubi_tools.c:137: error: 'UBI_DEV_NUM_AUTO' undeclared (first use in this function)
miscutils/ubi_tools.c:137: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
miscutils/ubi_tools.c:137: error: for each function it appears in.)
miscutils/ubi_tools.c:157: error: storage size of 'req' isn't known
miscutils/ubi_tools.c:165: error: 'UBI_IOCATT' undeclared (first use in this function)
miscutils/ubi_tools.c:157: warning: unused variable 'req'
miscutils/ubi_tools.c:171: error: 'UBI_IOCDET' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [miscutils/ubi_tools.o] Error 1
make: *** [miscutils] Error 2
```

How is it possible to solve that Error?

Can I disable this `ubi_tool` ? What effects will that have and how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines in .config:

```
CONFIG_UBIATTACH=y
CONFIG_UBIDETACH=y
CONFIG_UBIMKVOL=y
CONFIG_UBIRMVOL=y
CONFIG_UBIRSVOL=y
CONFIG_UBIUPDATEVOL=y
```

you won't have support for ubifs.